# Regex find word Java case insensitive

Tags: java, regex, string, list, filter

I want to find the following words in a list but I can't get my regex right in java.

**Ar**duino,Kat**ar**,Bac**ar**di

```
String keyWord = ar;
List<String> l = hubList.stream().filter(x -> x.matches("(?i)("+keyWord+")").collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: Try `x.matches("(?si).*"+keyWord+".*")`, or even `x.matches("(?si).*\\Q"+keyWord+"\\E.*")`

Comment: do i get you right, you want to get all strings that contain the substring "ar"?

Comment: @FalcoWinkler yes. the first regex worked! thanks… what does \E and \Q mean?

Answer (score 1):

To match `ar` inside a string (you need a whole word match with `matches()`!) you need to allow any symbols before and after the keyword.

Since *keyword* may contain (potentially) special regex characters (like `(` or `[`), it is safer to use `\Q...\E` operators that indicate that the characters between them are treated as literal characters.

Thus, I suggest

```
x.matches("(?si).*\\Q"+keyWord+"\\E.*")
```

If it is not the case and there will be just letters:

```
x.matches("(?si).*"+keyWord+".*")
```

Note that I also add `(?s)` singleline modifier to force a `.` to match *any* character, even a newline.

Comment: A understood, thanks again, so only (i) means case insensitive?

Comment: Yes, `i` in `(?i)` is just another way of specifying case-insensitive pattern matching.